# Does this image of 91-core OTRAG "asparagus-staging" show a real launch, or is it "space-art"?

Tags: identify-this-object, space-art, otrag

[This answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/38703/12102) to *Were there any non-state organizations to organize space flight and colonizations in the second half of the 20th century?* mentions [OTRAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OTRAG) and links to Astronautix's [OTRAG page](http://www.astronautix.com/o/otrag.html).

The images below are from the Astronautix page. The first image shows what looks like a very large close-packed hexagonal grouping of "asparagus" staging. With six cores on a side I calculate a total of 91 cores that would serve as multiple stages.

**Question:** The image shows the rocket launching, with firey exhaust and a launch tower next to it, but is this a real photo or just a simulation or "space-art"?

---

[image: OTRAG from Astronautix]

[image]

[image: OTRAG from Astronautix] [image: OTRAG from Astronautix]

Comment: companion question: [Are these sliding ullage bulkheads in the OTRAG rocket? How do they seal?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/38705/12102)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fake; that's an Atlas launch tower and the flames are from an Atlas (although it looks like they have been edited). The flames don't match the OTRAG at all.

This shot isn't exactly the same but it's close, I believe it's the same camera location.

[image]

Image from here: https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/image/spacecraft/mercury_atlas_9.jpg

side by side makes me think this actually might be the exact source image

[image]

Comment: Excellent *space-detective* work, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

According to [Gunter's Space Page](https://space.skyrocket.de/doc_lau/otrag.htm), none of the OTRAG test flights used more than four modules. I believe this must be an artist's impression of a 91-module booster.